# Increase width from 0 to a 100% with css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i want to increase my width from 0 to a 100.

I've tried this:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#underline").animate({width: '250px'});
    };
    </script>
```

To make it increase it's width but it won't work. I've also done some research too see if it's possible with css, but i keep ending up with tutorials on hover effects.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error:
Closing bracket missing for document.ready

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#underline").animate({width: '250px'});
    });
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rLqqZE

Comment: :) :) ... you were 3 mins late my friend

Comment: i was identifying myself selecting street numbers with captacha :(

Comment: I have a loader and i would like it to animate after the loader is done.

Comment: @Notorious_Creed i have updated codepen with loader-  http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wWYYJE

Comment: @NagaSaiA Agains thanks for the quick response, but what i meant was for the animation te play after the page was loaded ^.^

Comment: Use window.bind - $(window).bind("load", function() {

Comment: @NagaSaiA i don't want to be a pain hehe. But the first one you send was great, but what i meant was that after the circle is done loading which is actually a delay. that the animation for underline starts

Comment: @Notorious_Creed can you create another question clearly with screenshot or loader code :) and mark this post as answered

Answer (score 2):

Your script looks good. Just that, I think you are missing a parenthesis there which is breaking your code. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#underline").animate({width: '250px'});
 });
//^------- here
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#underline").css('width', '250px');
    });
```

Working fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/hbtv3bkn/